# How to use JSON values in Oracle PL/SQL Inner Join SELECT statement

Tags: sql, json, oracle

I have two tables T1 and T2. In T1 I have a column C1 that contains a value :

```
"businessKeys": [{
            "name": "REF_ID",
            "value": "2634",
            "type": "Integer"
        }, {
            "name": "VERSION_REF_ID",
            "value": "91950",
            "type": "Integer"
        }, {
            "name": "SCENARIO",
            "value": "test1",
            "type": "String"
        }, {
            "name": "CYCLE",
            "value": "2021Q3-1",
            "type": "String"
        }
    ]
```

In Table T2 I have a column C2 :

```
{
    "businessKeys": [{
            "name": "REF_ID",
            "value": "2634",
            "type": "Integer"
        }, {
            "name": "VERSION_REF_ID",
            "value": "91950",
            "type": "Integer"
        }, {
            "name": "SCENARIO",
            "value": "test1",
            "type": "String"
        }, {
            "name": "CYCLE",
            "value": "2021Q3-1",
            "type": "String"
        }
    ],
    "secondaryKeys": [{
            "name": "EQUATION_ID",
            "value": "Value1",
            "type": "String"
        }, {
            "name": "EQUATION_NAME",
            "value": "Value 2",
            "type": "String"
        }, {
            "name": "USECASE",
            "value": "Test Use Case",
            "type": "String"
        }, {
            "name": "RECORD_DATE",
            "value": "07-01-2023",
            "type": "Date"
        }, {
            "name": "OUTPUT_VALUE",
            "value": "0",
            "type": "Float"
        }
    ]
}
```

How do I get "secondaryKeys" from T2.C2 if I match "businessKeys"?

If it wasn't JSON fields I would have a simple SELECT :

```
SELECT t2.secondaryKeys from T1 t1, T2 t2
WHERE t1.businessKeys = t2.businessKeys
```

I also need to retrieve certain value from SecondaryKeys : OUTPUT_VALUE.

Comment: The comparison with "no JSON" is not relevant. In your current data, each row in each table contains an entire **table** in the JSON column. Do the tables also have additional columns, by which you match rows between the tables (never mind the JSON columns)? Otherwise you would compare each JSON, from every row in the first table, to every JSON (from every row) in the second table. That doesn't make a lot of sense. Please tell us more about the tables, and the exact desired output - rather than just generalities.

Comment: Yes, table do have other columns but can't match them.I need to match C1.businessKeys to C2.businessKeys and retreive C2.secondaryKeys.OUTPUT_VALUE

Comment: I don't understand. The first table may have 30,000 rows and the second table 18,000 rows. There is no C1.businessKeys; every row in the first table has a businessKeys array in column C1, and similar for the second table. Are you going to check each of the 30,000 JSON from the first table against each of the 18,000  JSON from the second table? That makes no sense.

Comment: Well, first table will always be very small 10-15 values at most. And yes, I need to match business key Element by Element  and as long as every element in BusinessKey matches I need to get "secondaryKeys.OUTPUT_VALUE".  That's the task and I don't have any control over the structure of the tables and its content.

Comment: OK. What is the exact format you need for the output? What is your Oracle version? (Very important!) And: order in an array has meaning. Will the different members of businessKeys always be the same? (Having those in an array, instead of a JSON object with ***keys*** REF_ID, etc., seems wrong - but perhaps there is a reason for this, and even if there isn't, perhaps it's not within your power to fix it.)

Comment: I need to get the value of the element :

{
            "name": "OUTPUT_VALUE",
            "value": "0",
            "type": "Float"
        }

in this case it's "0".
Oracle version is 12c, 12.1.0.2.0

Order in BusinessKeys array will always stay the same. My task is to compare values and make sure they match. The structure is always the same with 4 elements : REF_ID,VERSION_REF_ID, SCENARIO, CYCLE. As long as their values match I have a match on businessKey.

Comment: OK. 12.1 is when JSON was first introduced in Oracle - so there is no JSON_EQUAL condition for example. This can be done, but it won't be fast. (I'll post a solution after I write it up.) So, just to clarify, you just need a single column of values in the output, such as 0? Will you know which businessKeys array was the one that matched between the tables, leading to the value 0? Or do you not care about that? If you do, then the output can't just be "0" with no reference to where it came from.

Comment: yes, that's what I need - single element value. I am picking up a record based on some other key in T1 table. In this record there is a a field that contains a JSON element ( businessKey ).
Surdo Code :
SELECT "secondaryKey[2].value"  FROM T1 t1, T2 t2, where t1.c1.businessKey = t2.c2.businessKey and t1.key = <someValue>

Answer (score 0):

I assumed there's an additional column `id` in table `t1`, which you use to select a (unique?) row from `t1`. Notice where that goes: the `where` clause at the end of subquery `q1` in the `with` clause.

This solution depends critically on the JSON structure being very rigid: the `businessKeys` object value is always an array with four object members with exactly those keys AND exactly those values for the key `name`, and similarly for `secondaryKeys`. These can be relaxed easily in later Oracle versions, which support filter expressions in JSON paths, the JSON_EQUAL condition, etc.; in Oracle 12.1 (and even 12.2) it would be quite a bit harder.

```
with
  q1 (bk_ref_id, bk_version_ref_id, bk_scenario, bk_cycle) as (
    select j1.bk_ref_id, j1.bk_version_ref_id, j1.bk_scenario, j1.bk_cycle
    from   t1 cross apply
           json_table(c1, '$.businessKeys'
               columns ( bk_ref_id         integer  path '$[0].value'
                       , bk_version_ref_id integer  path '$[1].value'
                       , bk_scenario       varchar2 path '$[2].value'
                       , bk_cycle          varchar2 path '$[3].value'
                       )
           ) j1
    where  t1.id = 101                   -------- INPUT ID GOES HERE --------
  )
, q2 (bk_ref_id, bk_version_ref_id, bk_scenario, bk_cycle, sk_output_value) as (
    select j2.bk_ref_id, j2.bk_version_ref_id, j2.bk_scenario, j2.bk_cycle,
           j2.sk_output_value
    from   t2 cross apply
           json_table(c2, '$'
               columns 
                   ( sk_output_value number path '$.secondaryKeys[4].value'
                   , nested path '$.businessKeys'
                         columns ( bk_ref_id         integer  path '$[0].value'
                                 , bk_version_ref_id integer  path '$[1].value'
                                 , bk_scenario       varchar2 path '$[2].value'
                                 , bk_cycle          varchar2 path '$[3].value'
                                 )
                   )
           ) j2
  )
select q2.sk_output_value
from   q1 join q2 using (bk_ref_id, bk_version_ref_id, bk_scenario, bk_cycle)
;
```